# Feeding all textbox on the basis of the value of first textbox jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have many textbox with class "price",
All i want to do is feed all other textbox with the same value as the first textbox. here is my code but its not working.

```
$firstprice=$("."+$sectionwrapper).find(".price").first().val();
$("."+$sectionwrapper).find(".price:eq(0)").nextAll(".price").val($firstprice);
```

where am i going wrong? any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="section-1">
    <div id="bookin-ad-wrapper">
        <div class="booking-wrapper booking-wrapper-5">
            <ul>
            <li><label class="w50">Pris kr</label><input type="text" value="" class="price numeric required" name="txtSection[1][5][price]" style=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="booking-wrapper booking-wrapper-6">
            <ul>
            <li><label class="w50">Pris kr</label><input type="text" value="" class="price numeric required" name="txtSection[1][6][price]"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="booking-wrapper booking-wrapper-0">
            <ul>
             <li><label class="w50">Pris kr</label><input type="text" value="" class="price numeric required" name="txtSection[1][0][price]"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**$sectionwrapper denotes class "section-1"**

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us html or make a fiddle?

Comment: Yeah, only after seeing the HTML we can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this  [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/npwLt/)

```
$('input.price').val($('.price').eq(0).val())
```

or this way

```
  $('input.price:gt(0)').val($('input.price').eq(0).val());
```

or using  first operator.

```
$('input.price').val($('input.price').first().val());
```

you can hook it in whichever event you want.  may be click, on change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.price:gt(0)').val($('input.price:eq(0)').val());
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/gEcTB/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhu5013/LmrRz/)

```
$(".price").on("change",function()
               {$(".price").val($(".price").first().val())
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this:

  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".section-1").find(".price").first().blur(function () {
              var firstprice=$(".section-1").find(".price").first().val();
              //alert("val"+ firstprice);
              if(firstprice)
              $(".section-1").find(".price").val(firstprice);
        });
  });
```